# Effect Vertical Slide (name unknown)

Tags: effects

most of you know the effect of vertical sliders.
For example your music-library in iTunes:
you have the artist and with a vertical slide (direction is to the right) you'll get his albums.

I hope it is clear, which effect i mean ;) (sorry for my bad english - I'm not a native speaker)

My question is: how is this effect called in jQuery (only the name and maybe a good tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery documentation:

**[Sliding](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/)**

You have `slideDown()`, `slideUp()`, `slideToggle()`.

Here is good tutorial explaining vertical and horizontal sliding with jQuery.

**[Slide Elements in Different Directions](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)**

Comment: thank you - is it possible to slide from one to another side - like in itunes from artist to album?